# Enable SSRS My Reports using Express edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-express

Is there a way to enable the “[My Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155893.aspx)” feature in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 when I am using [SQL Server 2008 Express edition with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en)?

As I am using Express edition, I [cannot connect SQL Server Management Studio to Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx): -

> "SQL Server Management Studio Express
>   cannot be used to administer a report
>   server".

I am using the [Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx) Browser interface for SSRS administration. The option to enable “[My Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155893.aspx)” appears not to be in Report Manager for SSRS 2008 so is there another way to enable this option, command line maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is, honestly, a guess as I don't have SQL 2008 Express to test this on - but it definitely works on SQL 2005 standard.*

I think you can configure the property using `rs.exe`

Create a text file (I'm assuming you'll call it myReportsEnable.rss) and add the following text to it:

```
Public Overridable Sub Main()
    SetSystemProperties
End Sub

Private Sub SetSystemProperties()

    Dim Properties(0) As Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2008.[Property]
    Properties(0) = New Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2008.[Property]
    Properties(0).Name = "EnableMyReports"
    Properties(0).Value = "True"
    RS.SetSystemProperties(Properties)
End Sub
```

(I'm getting this from SQL2005, so I'm assuming that `Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2008` is the right type to use - apologies if it's not)

Save the file, then execute it from a command line using `rs.exe`:

```
rs -i myReportsEnable.rss -s http://~YourServerName~/reportserver
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, making this the accepted answer after it worked for Carlo. I have not tested this method, I am now using SQL Server developer edition (see my answer to this question) where "My Reports" works.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Harper's answer worked for me on an express edition instance of SRSS 2008, but only after I changed the names back to "ReportingServices2005".

I had also tried just changing the value for "enablemyreports" in the ConfigurationInfo table from "false" to "true", but that attempt just gave me an error in Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not entirely answer the question I asked! However, I got around this issue by using [SQL Server developer edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx) for my SQL Server installation used for training etc. Although not free like [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en), it is inexpensive.

Using [SQL Server developer edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx) allowed me to enable the ["My Reports"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155893.aspx) feature.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for [SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am already using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services and you can't connect Management Studio to reporting services.

Comment: Sorry about that... I realized I linked to the wrong page... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx

You are looking for the Business Intelligence Development Studio?!