# SSRS - Limit users to upload certain file types?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to limit the types of files that can be uploaded into SSRS 2008?

So far I have only been able to completely restrict file upload. We just want to limit it to certain file types.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there's an explicit way to limit the file extensions that can be uploaded, but a solution for you may be to implement the "My Reports" feature in SSRS.  With this feature, you can grant each user their own reports folder which you can then edit permissions to allow them to upload reports, but not additional resources.

[This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3039/sql-server-reporting-services-report-manager-tips-and-tricks/) describes how to turn on the feature and includes a lot of useful information on the My Reports feature.  This gives any administrators access to the user's folder, however each individual gets their own separate folder which makes collaboration a bit more difficult.

I believe unchecking the "Manage Resources" permission in the image below would do what you need.

[image]

EDIT: Sorry, looks like you have SSRS 2008.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611625/enable-ssrs-my-reports-using-express-edition) should help get MyReports working in 2008 if the above doesn't work.